# Error deploying WAR file to Jboss EAP 6.3

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, ear

I tried to build a war file which contains web services which deploys in JBOSS AS 6.3 EAP Beta

But, in JBOSS EAP it gave me the following error:

```
2014-10-08 11:06:11,693 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."My.ear"."MyWebApp.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."My.ear"."MyWebApp.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "MyWebApp.war" of deployment "My.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-11.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-11]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFDeploymentException: JBWS024101: Could not find endpoint config name: Standard-Endpoint-Config
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:118)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:137)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-11.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-11]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFDeploymentException: JBWS024101: Could not find endpoint config name: Standard-Endpoint-Config
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.ServerBeanCustomizer.configureEndpoint(ServerBeanCustomizer.java:150)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.ServerBeanCustomizer.customize(ServerBeanCustomizer.java:71)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.configuration.JBossWSNonSpringConfigurer.customConfigure(JBossWSNonSpringConfigurer.java:58)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.configuration.JBossWSNonSpringConfigurer.configureBean(JBossWSNonSpringConfigurer.java:45)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.configureObject(EndpointImpl.java:507)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:411)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 13 more
```

It has previously been working in JBOSS 7.2Final

What is wrong with my deployment or with my application?

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your standalone-xxx.xml file doesn't have the `Standard-Endpoint-Config` endpoint defined. Check your webservices subsystem (in standalone-xxx.xml), It should have something similar to this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
```